# Is there any way to post multiple requests using one post method Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, post

For example I have a users table and a orders table and I want to add details of multiple orders for the same user but using Post method only once.
Is there any way to do so??

Here is the order Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/users/{userId}/orders")
public List<Orders> addOrder(@RequestBody Orders order,@PathVariable BigInteger userId) {
    order.setUser(new User(userId," "," "," "));
    ordersService.addOrder(order);
}
```

**Order Entity:-**

```
@Entity
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private BigInteger id;
    private String date;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Orders(){}
    public Orders(BigInteger id, String date,BigInteger userId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.user=new User(userId," "," "," ");
    }

    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

}

What i want is using the same post method of the Order Controller ,post multiple orders for a single userid

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code.

Comment: Well i haven't been able to figure out how to tackle this particular problem.

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely. Let suppose you want to post multiple orders in a single request. Consider each order have properties like `orderName`, `orderNumber` and so. So you can do it like

### Json Request

```
{  
   "orders":[  
      {  
         "orderName":"order1",
         "orderNumber":"Ref-1"
      },
      {  
         "orderName":"order2",
         "orderNumber":"Ref-2"
      }
   ]
}
```

### Controller Method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/users/{userId}/orders", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Orders> addOrder(@RequestBody List<Order> orders,@PathVariable BigInteger userId) {
       //do whatever you want
    }
```

Where `Order` should be a simple pojo with required parameters/fields.